# How to verify hash password in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT users_email,users_password FROM `site_users` WHERE  users_email = :users_email");
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email', $_POST["email"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (password_verify('' . $_POST["password"] . '', $result[0]["users_password"]))
    echo 'Valid';
else 
    echo 'Not Valid';
```

The code always echoes `not valid`. What is the problem in my code?

First, I am fetching the Hash_Password of a specific email and then using PHP function `Password_Verify` to verify.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just `$result["users_password"]` instead of `$result[0]["users_password"]`? `print_r($result);` to double check.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Toby If I do `password_verify("lol","$2y$10$FdTv/ZH8j9hYDZIm0D6ZzeQPSEo7f7UritF9o.NPKYk")` then it returns false. Are you sure that original password is `lol` so we can check what's the problem here?

Comment: Why concatenate empty strings?

Comment: ??? what you mean?

Comment: `''.$_POST["password"].''` the `''` and `.`s are unneeded and possibly malforming your result.

Comment: I tried to remove it, still same result

Comment: @Toby How are you generating hashed string to store in db? If we try to find hash algo of `$2y$10$FdTv/ZH8j9hYDZIm0D6ZzeQPSEo7f7UritF9o.NPKYk`, it gives *unknown hash format.*

Comment: @Toby What is the size of your password field in database?

Answer (score 0):

`password_verify()` is used for checking a password is properly hashed or not. For more info on this function: [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

There are several things you need to confirm

1. At first, make sure that you are getting value inside `$result[0]["users_password"]`
2. then try to reproduce it using single quote with your hashed password

Lastly please send your hashed data to check it from our end :)

```
$data = password_hash('lol',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pass = 'lol';
if(password_verify($pass, 
'$2y$10$kGlXgFHcw.wwF4N.3ZR2suIXzmwyv1AHxEwz14WGN12NM.9ETaexe')){
 echo "done";
}
else{
echo 'not_done';
}
```

This is an working example. change this code with your posted data, hope you will get result

Comment: This is the result of `$result[0]["user_password"]` `$2y$10$FdTv/ZH8j9hYDZIm0D6ZzeQPSEo7f7UritF9o.NPKYk` 

Original password is `lol` .

Comment: Btw, If I type `lol` instead of `$_POST["password"]` , the code works. But ofc, i need $_POST...What's wrong?

Comment: $data = password_hash('lol',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pass = 'lol';
if(password_verify($pass, '$2y$10$kGlXgFHcw.wwF4N.3ZR2suIXzmwyv1AHxEwz14WGN12NM.9ETaexe')){
 echo "done";
}
else{
 echo 'not_done';
}

This is an working example. change this code with your posted data, hope you will get result.

Comment: It works...But If i put `$_POST["password"]` instead of `lol`..It do not work

Comment: Then the problem is with your $_POST["password"] value. echo it & check what it's returning, share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many quotes in below line. Try replacing

```
if (password_verify(''.$_POST["password"].'', $result[0]["users_password"]))
```

with

```
if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $result[0]["users_password"]))
```

because `$_POST["password"]` should be string. If you are unsure about it, you can do also this

```
$pwd = "" .$_POST["password"]; //force cast to string
if (password_verify($pwd, $result[0]["users_password"]))
{
    echo 'Valid';
} 
else 
    echo 'Not Valid';
}
```

Comment: Still same result, always not valid